# How to get TableViewCell indexPath in nestled CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I've got a table view with collection views inside the table view cells. What I'm trying to do is get the indexPath of each table view cell in the collection view.

So for example if the `indexPath.row` of the table view cell is 1, the collection view inside that particular table view cell should be able to get that.

I've been mostly successful in my attempt. I created a variable `cellIndexPath` in `TableViewCell.swift`, this is set in `cellForRow` in `TableView.swift`. Then I can use the value in the collection view `cellForItem` which is also in `TableViewCell.swift` (since its nestled).
The problem with this is the values change as you scroll through the table view and collection view. As you scroll through a collection view with wrong values and it loads more cells the values become correct. I solved this by adding

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

The values are now all correct but there is still another issue. If 3 tableview cells are on the screen for example and I scroll to the end of the collection view in (table view) cell 1, cell 4 then has a collection view thats scrolled to the end as well, see video below. 
(I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this hence the question title. This question has been asked previously and have tried those methods but still hasn't worked properly. What I'm trying to achieve must be possible as its used in the App Store.)

[image]

**Update -** 
The data model I use is based on this format A1-2-3 where 1 is the category number (page number in app), 2 is the subcategory number (tableview row number) and 3 is the advert number (collection view cell number). The data is sorted into a 3D array for each category. `[/*category array*/[/*subcat array*/[/*advert data*/]]]`.

It would look something like this `[[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 4655.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4671.0], [0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 4663.0]], [[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4641.0]]]` - The first number is the category, second number the subcategory, third the advert, fourth the branch number, fifth the distance. These small arrays are in a larger one as there are many ads per subcategory. The are multiple subcategories hence the subcategory arrays are in another array this being the category array (3D array). Using this data the ad code Ax-y-z can be generated. In `cellForRow` this code and the branch number from the 3D array is used to get data from JSON file.

Comment: Your collection view shouldn't need to know the row number.  Why are you doing that? If it is so that the cell can access some data model, you should set a property on the cell with the relevant model object.

Comment: @Paulw11 It is for a data model. The TableView row is a subcategory number. The collectionview needs it so it knows which subcategory to load. How would I do what you are suggesting?

Comment: Your view controller would pass the relevant element from the array to the cell, not the whole array, then the cell doesn't need to know what row it is.

Comment: I’m still not exactly sure how to do that. Would you have any sample code a link to a guide etc? @Paulw11

Comment: You need to provide more code; what does your data model look like.  Show your `cellForRowAt:` and relevant code from your cell class

Comment: Updated the question. I didn't include code as my cellForRowAt: is quite long and mostly just using the array to get data from the JSON tree. I hope my explanation is clear otherwise I'll try ad some code. @Paulw11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174575/discussion-between-paulw11-and-henry).

Comment: It is still a bit hard to follow your data structure and it looks like it could benefit from having some structs defined to encapsulate it, but let me try and illustrate with a simple example; Say your data model was just 2 dimensions; `[[A,B,C,D],[E,F],[G,H,I,J]]` - so there is an array associated with each row. The number of rows is the count of the outer array (3).  In your `cellForRow` you would set a property of your cell so that it had the inner array it needed `cell.data = self.mainData[indexPath.row]` - now the cell doesn't need to know which row it is.